# ArrayList unexpected out of boundary result

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi guys i catch exception:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Code look like this:

```
 **ArrayList decoded = new ArrayList(10);
        decoded.add(1, "A");**
```

***I really don't get it what's wrong here ?***

Maybe someone could help me on this.

---

Basically i want to do this:
I have chars for example likes this:

```
ABCEDFG
```

And array with numbers:

```
321211
```

I need to take first char and first number. char write into S arrayList:

```
S={"A"};
```

Look at number and again write same char in that position if number is 3 then in third place:
(If number 1 then just write it in arrayList)

```
S={"A","","","A"}
```

And delete number and char from arrayLists. Now they look like this:

```
BCEDFG

21211
```

and again the same till the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're confused between *capacity* and *size*. This line:

```
ArrayList decoded = new ArrayList(10);
```

... creates a list with a *capacity* of 10 (it won't need to grow internally until the eleventh element is added), but a *size* of 0. The *only* index you can add anything is 0.

If you want to be able to set values at arbitrary positions, you should populate the list first, e.g. (using generics just because I hate using the raw types):

```
List<String> decoded = new ArrayList<String>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    decoded.add(""); // Or perhaps null
}

...
decoded.set(1, "S"): // This is now fine, replacing element 1
```

Alternatively, if you already know the size you want, you could use an array to start with - they have a *fixed* size, and each element is the default value for the element type (so `null` for strings, for example):

```
String[] decoded = new String[10];
decoded[1] = "S";
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `ArrayList`s are indexed from 0. To add at the first index you must use this:

```
decoded.add(0, "A");
```

Or to add to the end of the list so far (which I think is what you actually want here):

```
decoded.add("A");
```

Also, you cannot insert an element at index n unless you already have elements at indexes 0, 1, ... n-1. If you want to read and write to arbitrary indexes then you should either initialize your `ArrayList` with nulls at every index, or you could just use an array instead:

```
String[] decoded = new String[10];
decoded[1] = "A";
```

I'd also advise you *not* to delete from each element from the start of the ArrayList in a loop as this will give O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance. Instead you could use a queue. Or don't actually remove the elements from the list, but just have a counter that remembers how many elements have been used so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API doc of [ArrayList.add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29). It clearly says that method throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size()).`

And in your case when you insert an element at `index 1` by calling `decoded.add(1, "A")`, the `size()` of your list `decoded` is `0`.